# Align facebook button to the right

Tags: css

I try to align the facebook button to the right. The code for the like button is:

```
<div id="SocialDiv">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://PanoNest.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</div>
```

As you see, I placed it inside a div called `SocialDiv`, and then I tried adding the css:

```
.SocialDiv{
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your referencing a class called socialDiv in your css, not an id, which you have set in our markup. 
try #socialDiv{}

although i'm not 100% sure that will work because i'm not sure of the outcome you are seeking